# Differentials of matrix-valued functions (+ notation question)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm taking a course on Calculus on Manifolds, and the first lecture went over differentials of functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and we proved properties such as the chain rule and and extreme value theorem.

However, I'm struggling to grasp some concepts I'm trying to study for the homework. For example, letting $f, g: \mathbb{R}^d\to M_{n\times n}$ (where $M_{n\times n}$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices) be continuously differentiable functions, compute the differential $fg$.

First, we haven't dealt with matrix-valued functions, so I'm considering $M_{n\times n}$ as the set of all linear operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and thus $f, g$ both return other functions, I think. But, how can we compose $fg$, considering the domain and codomain don't match up? Also, my immediate idea was to jump to the chain rule, but that seems too straightforward, especially since we only proved the chain rule for real-valued functions and we haven't yet defined the differential for matrix-valued functions.

Answer (score 1):

One attempt may be to consider $fg$ as the mapping

$\begin{align*}
fd:\mathbb{R}^d & \to M_{n\times n}\\
p & \mapsto f(p)\cdot g(p)
\end{align*}$

where $f(p)\cdot g(p)$ is obtained by the standard matrix multiplication.

In this way, you can easily obtain the differential at $p$ of this map as follows: consider $p\in \mathbb{R}^d$, $0\neq V_p\in T_p \mathbb{R}^d$ and the curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^d$ satisfying $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=V_p$. Then $\gamma(t)=p+tV_p$ and

$\begin{align*}
d(fg)_p(V_p)&=\frac{d}{dt}(fg)(\gamma(t))\Bigg|_{t=0}\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\Big(f(p+tV_p)\cdot g(p+tV_p)\Big)\Bigg|_{t=0}\\
&=df_p(V_p) \cdot g(p)+f(p)\cdot dg_p(V_p)\end{align*}$

where we are identifying $M_{n\times n}\simeq \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$ and thus $T_q M_{n\times n}\simeq M_{n\times n}$ for any $q\in M_{n\times n}$.